# How can I implement background notifications in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am developing an example app, with the most important concepts (notifications, consumption of apis, etc.).

I can generate notifications, but I always have to have the application open, even in the background. The idea is that although the application is closed, there is some process that allows me every time interval to execute an action and if it is true, it shows a notification.

For example, most of us use the Facebook, Instragram and Whatsup apps, and these applications, even if they are closed when there is a new message, show us a notification. It is really what I would like to achieve.

If you could help me, I would really appreciate it and thank you for what you have helped me so far.

**How could you do this to make it work for Android and IOS?**

**I thank you very much for your help.**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/ similar with IOS

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I make my app send out notifications when it's loaded but not running in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622443/how-can-i-make-my-app-send-out-notifications-when-its-loaded-but-not-running-in)

Comment: @Guillermo, It seems that you can try to use FCM notification to push notification when app closed, this is article about [Remote Notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for push notifications. Please have a look at the below articles for sending push notifications in Xamarin.

https://xmonkeys360.com/2019/12/08/xamarin-forms-fcm-setup-configuration-part-i/

https://xmonkeys360.com/2019/12/09/fcm-configuration-in-xamarin-forms-part-ii/

The codes inside the button click in the sample demonstrated can be moved to an API call to get it working for what you are looking for.

Hope it helps...